# TableView shows two selected rows

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, selection

I'm setting the selected row in code, the correct row is selected (highlighted). Then I tap on another row in the TableView and that row becomes selected, but the previous row remains highlighted. If instead, I tap on the first row before selecting a difference row, that row becomes the only row highlighted. Until I tap on the originally selected (set in code) row, it remains highlighted no mater which other rows I select.

Any idea why the Table does not reset the highlighting?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Store the `indexPath` of the row you selecting through code in `selectedRow` and then try this `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRow animated:YES];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: That's a good idea - unfortunately when I call TableView.DeselectRow nothing happens. Not sure if this is a MonoTouch bug or what...

Comment: Ohh..I dnt hav xperiance in monotouch app..so i cant get you the reason..but in other one, this idea should wrk..